# Merge XMLs based on mapping condition

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, jaxb

I am looking for a best way to merge XMLs which satisfies certain mapping conditions

XML1 :

```
  <root>
        <key>123<key>
  </root>
```

XML2 :

```
  <root>
       <base_node_1>
           <key>123<key>
           <data1>aaa</data1>
           <data2>bbb</data2>
       </base_node_1>
       <base_node_2>
           <key>456<key>
           <data1>xxx</data1>
           <data2>yyy</data2>
       </base_node_2>
  </root>
```

Expected Output:

```
<root>
        <key>123<key>
        <data1>aaa</data1>
        <data2>bbb</data2>
  </root>
```

Match 'key' from XML1 to the block in XML2 . If match found , map the attributes into final output xml.

Thing here to note is that 'base_node' in XML2 tag could change . There are around 100 possible tags.

Converting the XMLs to Java objects using JAXB and mapping them in java is one way .
But JAXB looks complex considering the structure of second xml - XML2

Is there a better way to do this? May be XPATH based mapping ?

Comment: That is easy in XSLT, easier in XSLT 2 or 3 where you can use the `key` function with a third argument being the document to search. But the sample is rather simple, it is not clear whether there are always only two child elements of the root element in the second document or which structure you wanted if there were more of them and several matches, if you really want to merge all data together.

Comment: @MartinHonnen Thanks for your inputs . Regarding your question . Second XML can have more than 2 child elements . And only one block is expected to match here .

Comment: The see my answer, it should solve it.

Answer (score 1):

XSLT 2 or 3:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">
    
  <xsl:param name="key-doc">
  <root>
        <key>123</key>
  </root>      
  </xsl:param>
  
  <xsl:key name="lookup" match="root/key" use="."/>

  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="/*">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:copy-of select="*[key('lookup', key, $key-doc)]/*"/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

First doc is inlined for self-containedness of example but of course could be declared as `<xsl:param name="key-doc" select="doc('xml1.xml')"/>` instead.

Even in XSLT 1, without using a key and by using e.g. `<xsl:param name="key-doc" select="document('xml1.xml')"/>` you can simply select

```
  <xsl:template match="/*">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:copy-of select="*[key = $key-doc/root/key]/*"/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

to find the matching element and copy its child elements through to the output.

Comment: Thanks. I will test this. Which XSLT implementation do you suggest ? JAXP or Saxon or anything else ? . I am looking for open source implementation . And other than the above I have some complex recursive mapping to be done , within blocks of same XML based on a mapping key

Comment: @amuru Use Saxon, it will provide you with the latest XSLT features.

Comment: @amuru, in the Java world it is usually easy to use Saxon 10 or 9 for XSLT 3 or 2 support instead of the JRE built-in, Xalan based XSLT 1 processor.

Comment: @MartinHonnen Above xsl worked for me . Is there a way to refer variable inside 'key' function for 'select; ? I am trying to do recursive mapping . So there is a variable which refers to block of xml elements. I want to use on this element as my select criteria for selecting the next block . Do you have any idea on this

Comment: @amuru, it is not clear to me how your new or extended problem with "recursive" mapping looks exactly. Consider to ask a new question with all necessary details about that.